# Getting info from the monitored process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, god

I am using god to monitor my delayed jobs. 
currently I suffer from exceeded memory consumption from time to time, 
I've set god to restart jobs exceeding 100MB. 
my question is: is there a way to get information from the current 
running job before god restarts it? 
this is crucial in order to know what process exactly causes the 
exceeded memory consumption

Thanks, 
Ran

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom behavior.  There are several examples in the source for [god](https://github.com/mojombo/god/tree/master/lib/god/behaviors).  In general, in [behavior.rb](https://github.com/mojombo/god/blob/master/lib/god/behavior.rb) you can see there is a function called before_restart() that you will need to replace with your custom logic when you subclass the Behavior class.  You will then need to add some code like `w.behavior(:your_new_behavior)` to your god config.

Note: I have not personally done this, but looking threw the code it looks like the way to go.